# MVC Application Hosting to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a mvc application. Instead of typing "\servername\applicationname\controller\action", can I use "\servername\applicationname" which redirects to "\servername\applicationname\controller\action" URL? How do I achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

By adding a new route in RouteConfig.cs:

```
context.MapRoute(
        "RouteName",
        "applicationName/{action}",
        new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" });
```

Take care of the sequence of your routes. The first match will take effect!

ASP.NET Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: so what would be URL in your browser? And i didn't get about new[] { "Name.Space.To.Controller"}). Thanks

Comment: new {} returns a new url object like controller/action. see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470521.aspx